# Column Grouping Does Not display Duplicates

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, grouping

I have created a report in SSRS R2. The report is using tablix and column wise grouping.

The result set of the matrix is working fine as expected except that the consecutive same column values(or duplicates) are not getting skipped in display. Whereas my SQL is working perfectly displaying all data.

eg:  sql Result set

```
      1
      1
      2
      3


 Tablix Display    (instead of)    Tablix Display

      1  2  3      (instead of )    1  1  2  3
```

Comment: provide your dataset query and what you have done in RDL for grouping. Screenshot will be helpful. with information that you provided it is not clear what is the issue and what you expect.

Comment: You probably need to provide more information but from what I can see, if you are using grouping on columns then, by default, you will not get duplicates. That's the point of grouping the like data together. If you need to separate data that is grouped then you must group at a more granular level. Until we see your data though it it's hard to give any more advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping on the field that returns that data, then it removes duplicates by design - that's the point of grouping.

You would need to group by a different field, or just have no grouping on the tablix and only the Details region.

See here for more information on grouping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs